# iOS - Expand local XML file

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser, local-files

I'm loading a XML file from an PHP API on my server. This XML is written down to the Documents folder.

I now want to get new XML Data from the API and don't want to download the whole file again, because it is very large. So I thought of sending the ID's of the XML-entries to the server so that it just sends back, what I don't have on my iPad already.

That won't be the problem. But how can I access the file and write lines not to the end?
The XML looks something like that (for example):

```
<items>
    <item id="0" name="Item one" photo="/images/products/one.png" />
    <item id="1" name="Item two" photo="/images/products/two.png" />
</items>
```

So I need to write the new datas string (`<item id="2" name="Item three" photo="/images/products/three.png" />`) inside the "items" node?

Thanks, with kind regards, Julian

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to need a better solution. You could use CoreData to create a local database with all your items (parsing them from the XML files).

Every time you grab the "new" xml, you update your CoreData database to reflect your new items. You can even use it to update the database if an item has changed (if needed).

Apple has an [interesting document to begin with CoreData programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html).

If you plan to be a long-time developer on apple-related technologies (iOS & OSX), CoreData is a great tool on your portfolio.